# IDbConnection issue Select vs Exists

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I'm having some difficulties understanding why my Exists-query fails.

*This is an issue in SS 4.0.22 sqlite32, in the pre-release 4.0.23 it works fine. Scroll down for solution*

I have three tables, Token, ServiceInstance and a mapping table TokenServiceInstance:

```
[Alias("Token")]
public class Token
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    [Alias("Id")]
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [References(typeof(Customer))]
    [Alias("CustomerId")]
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    [Index]
    [Alias("TokenString")]
    public string TokenString { get; set; }

    [Alias("MasterTokenId")]
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public int MasterTokenId { get; set; }

}

[Alias("ServiceInstance")]
public class ServiceInstance
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    [Alias("Id")]
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string ServiceName { get; set; }
}

[Alias("TokenServicesInstance")]
public class TokenServicesInstance
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    [Alias("Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [References(typeof(ServiceInstance))]
    [Alias("ServiceInstanceId")]
    public int ServiceInstanceId { get; set; }

    [References(typeof(Token))]
    [Alias("TokenId")]
    public int TokenId { get; set; }

    [Alias("Parameters")]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Parameters { get; set; }
}
```

I want to do a simple query, to find out if Token and ServiceInstance is mapped given a certain TokenString in Token and a certain ServiceName in ServiceInstance.

I have this SqlExpression:

```
SqlExpression<TokenServicesInstance> expr = db.From<TokenServicesInstance>();
        expr.Join<TokenServicesInstance, Entities.Token>()
            .Join<TokenServicesInstance, Entities.ServiceInstance>()
            .Where<Entities.Token>(token => token.TokenString == tokenString)
            .And<Entities.ServiceInstance>(si => si.ServiceName == serviceName);
```

If I grab the SQL from the expression in the debugger:

```
SELECT "TokenServicesInstance"."Id", "TokenServicesInstance"."ServiceInstanceId", "TokenServicesInstance"."TokenId", "TokenServicesInstance"."Parameters"
FROM "TokenServicesInstance" 
INNER JOIN "Token"  ON ("Token"."Id" = "TokenServicesInstance"."TokenId") 
INNER JOIN "ServiceInstance"  ON ("ServiceInstance"."Id" = "TokenServicesInstance"."ServiceInstanceId")
WHERE ("Token"."TokenString" = 'B') AND ("ServiceInstance"."ServiceName" = 'A')
```

When I use the expression in a Select, it yields rows if any:

```
db.Select<TokenServicesInstance>(expr);
```

But I'm not really interested in the rows, just if there are any, so I would like to use the Exists-method, however this throws an exception, using the exact same expression.

```
db.Exists<TokenServicesInstance>(expr)
```

Exception details:

```
An exception of type 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException' occurred in System.Data.SQLite.dll but was not handled in user code 
Additional information: SQL logic error or missing database
no such column: Token.TokenString
```

Any ideas why Select works fine and Exists throws an exception? How about my query, does it look right?

**Solution**

As a follow up on mythz' answer I tried with the pre-release of Servicestack, 4.0.23 in stead of my version 4.0.22 - now the code works without any issues.

Prying into the generated SQL shows that version 0.22 omits the JOIN-part of the query when counting rows.

4.0.23:

```
DEBUG: SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM "TokenServicesInstance" INNER JOIN "Token"  ON 
("Token"."Id" = "TokenServicesInstance"."TokenId") INNER JOIN "ServiceInstance"  ON 
("ServiceInstance"."Id" = "TokenServicesInstance"."ServiceInstanceId")
WHERE ("Token"."TokenString" = 'A') AND ("ServiceInstance"."ServiceName" = 'B')
```

4.0.22

```
DEBUG: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "TokenServicesInstance" WHERE ("Token"."TokenString" = 'A')     AND ("ServiceInstance"."ServiceName" = 'B')
```

Full test code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using NUnit.Framework;
using ServiceStack.DataAnnotations;
using ServiceStack.Logging;
using ServiceStack.OrmLite;
using ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite;
using WAAPI.ApiToken.Data.OrmLite.Entities;

namespace Db.Tests
{
public class ExistsTests
{
    [Test]
    public void Can_Select_exists_on_JOIN_expression()
    {
        LogManager.LogFactory = new ConsoleLogFactory();
        var tokenString = "A";
        var serviceName = "B";

        var factory = SetupFactory();

        using(var db = factory.OpenDbConnection())
        { 
            db.DropAndCreateTable<Token>();
            db.DropAndCreateTable<ServiceInstance>();
            db.DropAndCreateTable<TokenServicesInstance>();

            var q = db.From<TokenServicesInstance>();
            q.Join<TokenServicesInstance, Token>()
                .Join<TokenServicesInstance, ServiceInstance>()
                .Where<Token>(token => token.TokenString == tokenString)
                .And<ServiceInstance>(si => si.ServiceName == serviceName);

            Assert.That(db.Select(q).Count, Is.EqualTo(0));
            Assert.That(db.Exists(q), Is.False);
        }
    }

    private OrmLiteConnectionFactory SetupFactory()
    {
        var factory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(":memory:", SqliteOrmLiteDialectProvider.Instance);
        using (var db = factory.OpenDbConnection())
        {
            CreateMissingTables(db);
        }
        return factory;
    }

    protected void CreateMissingTables(IDbConnection db)
    {
        db.CreateTable<Token>();
        db.CreateTable<ServiceInstance>();
        db.CreateTable<TokenServicesInstance>();
    }
}
}

namespace WAAPI.ApiToken.Data.OrmLite.Entities
{
[Alias("TokenServicesInstance")]
public class TokenServicesInstance
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    [Alias("Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [References(typeof(ServiceInstance))]
    [Alias("ServiceInstanceId")]
    public int ServiceInstanceId { get; set; }

    [References(typeof(Token))]
    [Alias("TokenId")]
    public int TokenId { get; set; }

    [Alias("Parameters")]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Parameters { get; set; }
}

[Alias("ServiceInstance")]
public class ServiceInstance
{
    public string ServiceName { get; set; }

    [AutoIncrement]
    [Alias("Id")]
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

[Alias("Token")]
public class Token
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    [Alias("Id")]
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Index]
    public string TokenString { get; set; }

    [Alias("MasterTokenId")]
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public int MasterTokenId { get; set; }

    [ServiceStack.DataAnnotations.Ignore]
    public bool IsMasterToken
    {
        get { return MasterTokenId == 0; }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example works without issue in this test:

```
[Test]
public void Can_Select_exists_on_JOIN_expression()
{
    LogManager.LogFactory = new ConsoleLogFactory();
    var tokenString = "A";
    var serviceName = "B";

    db.DropAndCreateTable<Token>();
    db.DropAndCreateTable<ServiceInstance>();
    db.DropAndCreateTable<TokenServicesInstance>();

    var q = db.From<TokenServicesInstance>();
    q.Join<TokenServicesInstance, Token>()
        .Join<TokenServicesInstance, ServiceInstance>()
        .Where<Token>(token => token.TokenString == tokenString)
        .And<ServiceInstance>(si => si.ServiceName == serviceName);

    Assert.That(db.Select(q).Count, Is.EqualTo(0));
    Assert.That(db.Exists(q), Is.False);
}
```

Can you use make sure you've updated to the latest version of ServiceStack. If it's still an issue can you try the [latest version of ServiceStack on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet) which will ensure we're running the same version.

If it's still an issue can you update your question with the generated SQL, which you can get OrmLite to print with:

```
LogManager.LogFactory = new ConsoleLogFactory();
```

Comment: Turned out to be version 4.0.22 of SS. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you plan on releasing v4.0.23 to nuget.org anytime soon?

Comment: @HaraldV Yeah, aiming for a tomorrow release.